# SSMS - Show Client Statistics Number Of Select Statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

This has been asked but never fully answered I don't believe.

I have SSMS 2016 and turn on "Show Client Statistics".

I run this:

```
select 'Hello'
```

Client Statistics Say:

Number of SELECT statements: 2

Rows returned by SELECT Statements: 2

I don't have include execution plans turned on (suggestion of cause).

Any idea why these say 2 and not 1?

Thanks.

Comment: >>>Rows returned by SELECT Statements: 2<<< Did you try it with SET NOCOUNT ON?

Comment: Hi @sepupic Thats almost it!  Number of rows returned now says 1 but number of select statements still says 2

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Server Profiler, and watch what commands are being sent from SSMS to SQL Server.  You'll see there are two:

`select @@SPID;` and your query.

If you turn on Live Query Statistics, it will show 6 select statements: Yours, plus 5 more to gather the information you requested. You've altered the results by observing them.

[image]